# Overlap within a column for a common key in SQL

Tags: sql, self-join, cartesian-product

Any tips for how to convert a dataset that can have multiple values for each user to a dataset that shows the number of times two values overlap (are found for each user)?

Original hypothetical dataset:

```
User_ID Toured_State
A       NY
A       CA
A       FL
B       NY
B       TX
C       NY
C       CA
D       TX
```

Desired Dataset:

```
State_1     State_2     Count of users that toured both states
NY          CA          2
NY          TX          1
NY          FL          1
NY          NY          0
```

This would show how often a user touring one state also tours a second state.

My first thought was to do a self-join of the original dataset on the user id and then do a sum of the number of rows that are equal (taking into account reverse duplicates)? Is that the most efficient approach? Note that users are free to tour one or more states (not limited to two), including the same state twice. I've changed my example so I realize this specific case may not seem useful. Thanks for any tips in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this as:

```
select t1.state as state1, t2.state as state2, count(*)
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t1.user_id = t2.user_id and t1.state < t2.state
group by t1.state, t2.state
order by count(*) desc;
```

If you prefer to count users, then user `count(distinct user_id)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT *, RN= ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY User_ID Order BY User_ID) FROM @T 
)
SELECT 
    T1.Toured_State State_1, 
    T2.Toured_State State_2, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN T1.Toured_State = T2.Toured_State THEN NULL ELSE 1 END) [Count of users]
FROM CTE T1
    LEFT JOIN CTE T2 ON T1.User_ID = T2.User_ID AND T1.RN <= T2.RN
WHERE T1.RN = 1
GROUP BY T1.Toured_State, T2.Toured_State
ORDER BY [Count of users] DESC
```